# Excel - If cells in column equal number then return all data in row to new sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am lost... I know what I want this formula to do. But I can not make it work. I have tried vlookups, if then, match and so on to no avail.

I need to check data from one colomn and if it is equal to something then copy the entire row and place it onto another tab. So if I add something to the main tab, it will automatically add it to the new tab.

Example...
On Master tab: If data in column C is equal to 1, then copy all data in that row to tab team 1. repeat for all items marked 1.

Equal to 2, then copy row to team 2. Repeat for all items marked 2. And so on.

I appreciate anyones help in advance.

Comment: Seems like a VBA task. An alternative, albeit not great, is using pivot tables. The filter for each could be your Column-C value. The design would be tabular form, no grand totals, no subtotals. But you would need to remember to refresh the table after adding new data to the master sheet, which could be a simple macro I suppose.

Comment: To get a specific answer we need data samples. This can be done with Office 365 using FILTER() or in older versions using INDEX/AGGREGATE.

Comment: What Office version are you using
Is it office 365? Or an older version
Meanwhile if possible plz provide some data and result example to get the perfect solution

Comment: I suggest zooming out to a higher level of what you want to do. You mention copying data, but is this data that is passing through, or a reference source that is continually updated. By one person, by many? etc. I have seen a lot of constructions like this, where a more fundamental rethink allows a much simpler solution.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.